# Yii 2 : Trying to get property of non-object in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
       $model = new RoomTypes();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            // get the uploaded file instance. for multiple file uploads
            // the following data will return an array
            $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

            // store the source file name
            $model->room_type = $image->name;
            $imageName_1 = $model->room_type;
            $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));

            // generate a unique file name
            $model->pic_1 = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";

            // the path to save file, you can set an uploadPath
            // in Yii::$app->params (as used in example below)
            $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->pic_1;

            if($model->save()){
                $image->saveAs($path);
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->_id]);
            } else {
                // error in saving model
            }
        }
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public $image;

[['image'], 'safe'],
[['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
```

**View**

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'room_type')->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'image[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                                              'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true],
                                              'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png']
'slugCallback' => new JsExpression(function(room_type) 
{return room_type;},),]]); 
                                        ?>
```

Getting this error while uploading the file. **Also it's not accepting multiple image  for upload,** what's wrong with it?
How to achieve this multiple file upload???

Comment: don't create another variable `$image` just use [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4], and loop them  to store multiple images.

Comment: did corrections but still same error :(

Comment: can you show errors...

Comment: its in controller on line `$model->room_type = $image->name; `

Comment: you must ensure that your `Activeform` have an `option` `enctype => multipart/form-data` for multple file uploads.

Comment: ya its already there.

Answer (score -1):

You have missprint into model rule:

```
[['$image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
```

Should be

```
[['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
```